# NSPredicate for bilateral to-many relationship using Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate, relationship

I have an `Item` entity and a `Wishlist` entity. An item can be in multiple wishlists, and an wishlist can contain multiple items.

With the `WishlistTableViewController`, which lists all the wishlists, I want to select one and show all items inside that selected one. I send the `Wishlist` item to my `ItemTableViewController`, but I'm stuck at creating a predicate.

Basically, I want to get all items from a given wishlist.

In SQL, it would be something like:

`SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE WishlistItem.wishlist_id = wishlist.wishlist_id`

(may be missing inner joins, this is a very rough sketch, I haven't coded SQL in years)

Of course, Core Data automatically creates that middle table when we have many-to-many relationships, so how would I create a similar predicate using `NSPredicate`? I have my fetched results controller get all items at the moment, with no predicate (it's `nil`). That is the default behavior if a user does not come from a certain wishlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "wishlists" is the to-many relationship from *Item* to *Wishlist*, you can use
the following predicate to get all items that are related to the selected with list:

```
WhishList *selectedWishList = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY wishlists == %@", selectedWishList];
```

Answer (score 1):

With Core Data you'd normally set up a many-to-many relationship. `Item` would have a to-many relationship called `wishlists`, `Wishlist` would have a to-many relationship called `items`, and these relationships would be inverses of each other.

With those relationships, a predicate is unnecessary. If you want to get all the items for a wishlist, you'd just do

```
Wishlist *wishlist = ... // passed in from WishlistTableViewController

NSSet *items = [wishlist valueForKey:@"items"];
```

Or if you have custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses, you could do this:

```
NSSet *items = [wishlist items];
```

Comment: That's what my setup is! I forgot to explain it as well as you did, but in my Core Data design, that's how it's set up. I'm doing an `NSFetchRequest` to load the tableview up, so that's why I used the predicate. Can I load a table using `NSSet` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? Oh, and yes, my `NSManagedObjects` are subclassed.

Comment: You would have to sort the set into an array so that you'd know which item to use for which cell. You could either do a separate fetch with a sort descriptor (which would get you an array), or else get the set as I described and sort it using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`.